# Oracle SQL group row count by time intervals of 10 minutes

Tags: sql, oracle, count, group-by, intervals

I have a table in oracle which contains data such as the following

```
created_date       details  
01-Jan-16 04:45    abcd  
01-Jan-16 04:47    efgh  
01-Jan-16 04:53    ijkl  
01-Jan-16 04:54    mnop  
01-Jan-16 04:58    qrst
```

....etc

I want to be able to count the number of rows in the table for every 10 minutes
e.g.

```
Time    count
04:40       2
04:50       3
```

Created Date = Timestamp,
details = varchar

How would i do this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want these results for a specific date/time range with 0 values for intervals without any matches or do you want for all time but only ranges that have at least one match?

Comment: Also, if you had `01-Jan-16 04:45` and `02-Jan-16 04:46`, would you expect to see a count of 2 in a single 04:40 row, or would you expect to have separate 04:40 rows for each day?

Answer (score 11):

You can use TO_CHAR and SUBSTR to build the time string:

```
select
  substr(to_char(created_date, 'hh24:mi'), 1, 4) || '0' as created,
  count(*)
from mytable
group by substr(to_char(created_date, 'hh24:mi'), 1, 4) || '0'
order by substr(to_char(created_date, 'hh24:mi'), 1, 4) || '0';
```

Or with a subquery (a derived table), so as to have to write the date expression only once:

```
select created, count(*)
from
(
  select substr(to_char(created_date, 'hh24:mi'), 1, 4) || '0' as created
  from mytable
)
group by created
order by created;
```

Answer (score 5):

One method is to extract the hour and minute and do arithmetic:

```
select extract(hour from created_date) as hh,
       floor(extract(minute from created_date) / 6) as min,
       count(*)
from t
group by extract(hour from created_date),
         floor(extract(minute from created_date) / 6)
```

Answer (score 3):

An answer would be:

```
select trunc(sysdate, 'hh')+ trunc(to_char(sysdate,'mi')/10)*10/1440 from dual;
```

You can replace sysdate with your actual date/timestamp column and dual with your table

To understand the components, run:

```
select trunc(sysdate, 'hh') the_hour,
   to_char(sysdate,'mi') the_minutes,
   trunc(to_char(sysdate,'mi')/10)*10 minutes_truncated,
   trunc(to_char(sysdate,'mi')/10)*10/1440 part_of_the_day, --as 1 represents a day in oracle datetime system
   trunc(sysdate, 'hh')+ trunc(to_char(sysdate,'mi')/10)*10/1440 result
from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution if you want to make the group by on an actual timestamp value:

```
create table test_10_minutes_group_by (created_date timestamp, details varchar2(4));

insert into test_10_minutes_group_by values (systimestamp, 'aaa'); -- current time
insert into test_10_minutes_group_by values (systimestamp - 1/24/60, 'bbb'); -- 1 minute ago
insert into test_10_minutes_group_by values (systimestamp - 1/24/60 * 10, 'ccc'); -- 10 minutes ago
insert into test_10_minutes_group_by values (systimestamp - 1/24/60 * 20, 'ccc2'); -- 20 minutes ago
insert into test_10_minutes_group_by values (systimestamp - 1/24/60 * 25, 'abc');  -- 25 minutes ago
insert into test_10_minutes_group_by values (systimestamp - 1/24/60 * 30, 'xyz'); -- 30 minutes ago
insert into test_10_minutes_group_by values (systimestamp - 1/24/60 * 35, 'xyz2'); -- 35 minutes ago

select 
    actual_time,
    to_char(actual_time, 'hh24:mi:ss') pretty_date,
    count(1)
  from (
    select 
        trunc(created_date, 'mi') /*remove seconds*/ -  1/24/60 * mod(extract (minute from created_date), 10) /*substract units digit from minutes*/ actual_time, 
        details
      from 
        test_10_minutes_group_by 
  ) 
  group by actual_time;
```