# Group by period of time in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, oracle11g, timestamp

I am trying to group part of my data by a given period of time using a timestamp element, and count the number of the element in the group, but I have not been very successful after many attempts.

First of all I start with this data:

```
     REQ_DATA            PROVIDER_NAME
24/01/2023 12:01:01         PRO_1
24/01/2023 12:03:01         PRO_1
24/01/2023 12:00:01         PRO_1
24/01/2023 12:05:01         PRO_1
24/01/2023 12:12:01         PRO_1
24/01/2023 12:18:01         PRO_1
24/01/2023 12:18:50         PRO_1
24/01/2023 12:18:54         PRO_2
```

What I want to get is a result like that (the period being **10 minutes**):

```
                TIME_FILTER                 PROVIDER_NAME      COUNT
24/01/2023 12:01:01 - 24/01/2023 12:05:01        PRO_1           4
24/01/2023 12:12:01 - 24/01/2023 12:18:54        PRO_1           3
24/01/2023 12:18:54 - 24/01/2023 12:18:54        PRO_2           1
```

The TIME_FILTER column could be avoided, I put it here to better understand what I want to do.

The solution should be compatible with Oracle 11g.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34723120/oracle-sql-group-row-count-by-time-intervals-of-10-minutes)  answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle SQL group row count by time intervals of 10 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34723120/oracle-sql-group-row-count-by-time-intervals-of-10-minutes)

Comment: No, because it will sort by static time period, i.e. a specific time is selected and the period is always added up until the end of the rows.

What I need is that the first element varies and the period is added in EACH GROUPING.

Comment: @ÁlvarodelaFlorBonilla So you want the TIME_FILTER to be 10 minutes from the first event, and not necessarily in time buckets like 00-10, 10-20, etc? If so, you might want to modify your sample data to show a result count that would be different based on how the 10-minute buckets are defined.